# How can I make scanf and printf functions of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, printf, scanf

I am trying to make two separate functions, one for a reading of an array, and another one for prining it. 
My code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read(int n, int v[100])
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
}

void print(int n, int v[100])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",v[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int v[100];
    int n;
    read(n,v);
    print(n,v);
}
```

But if i read something like this

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

it prints this:

```
12345167773430408951321408978481140419686004089785612740906704021677734340894
```

and other numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: read() doesn't set the value of n in main--it sets a local copy. You need to make read take a pointer and pass in &n.

Comment: `read(n,v);` and `print(n,v);` are using the *uninitiaised variable* `n`.

Comment: You may want to print some whitespace between your numbers. `%d` doesn't print any.

Comment: What @LeeDanielCrocker said. Or just have `read()` return the count instead of using a pointer parameter.

Comment: The array `int v[100];` printed in `void print` is also unintialised. Please understand that local variables defined in a function have indeteminate value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a program that does what you want it do to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function Prototypes Start
void array_reader(int array_length, int array[]);
void array_printer(int array_length, int array[]);
// Function Prototypes End


int main(void) {

    int max_amt_to_scan;
    printf("How many numbers would you like to scan in?\n");
    scanf("%d", &max_amt_to_scan);

    int num_array[max_amt_to_scan];

    printf("Please enter %d numbers!\n", max_amt_to_scan);
    array_reader(max_amt_to_scan, num_array);

    printf("The numbers you entered were:\n");
    array_printer(max_amt_to_scan, num_array);

    return 0;
}


// Scans or reads in numbers, into an array
void array_reader(int array_length, int array[]) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < array_length) {

        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}


// Prints out an array of numbers
void array_printer(int array_length, int array[]) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < array_length) {

        if (i == (array_length - 1)) {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%d, ", array[i]);
        }
            i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize `n` in `main`. The `n` in `main` and the `n` in `read` are different variables, so changing `n` in `read` doesn't affect the `n` in `main`, which remains uninitialized and hence you have an undefined behaviour in `print`.

You have to either pass `n` as a pointer or `read` must return `n`:

```
void read(int &n, int v[100])
{
    scanf("%d",n);
    for(int i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int v[100];
    int n;
    read(&n,v);
    print(n,v);
}
```

or

```
int read(int v[100])
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int v[100];
    int n = read(v);
    print(n,v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should look like:

```
void read(int *array, int size)
{
    printf("Now enter %d values:\n", size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", array + i);
        /* array + i = &(array[i]) */
    }
}

void print(int *array, int size)
{
    printf("Here is your array:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d%c", array[i], i == size - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
        /* ternary puts spaces and \n at the end */
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter array size :\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];  /* Keep one array */
    read(array, size);
    print(array, size);
}
```

Comment: @FredLarson Wow thanks, i never realized that i was wrong. I am sure that i have it seen it written like that somewhere, too many wrong info on internet nowadays...

Comment: Maybe you were using the same lousy book quoted in the question.

Comment: @FredLarson No, i actually never opened a "book", only online resources. I suspect wrong info just survives for a long time.

Comment: Learning C from online resources is probably not a good idea. Note that C functions are call by value, so I suspect that a function prototype like `void read(int n, int v[100]);` confuses many into thinking that the value of the array is passed in the function call. Yet: 1) array types in function prototypes are adjusted to appropriate pointers, making the actual prototype `void read(int n, int *v);`, and 2) arrays decay to pointers to their first elements in most expressions, so `read(n, v);` passes a pointer to the first element of `v` by value (a copy) to `read()`.

Comment: In all expressions except `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and when used with the unary `&` operator. [6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators (p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- tag-team instruction! Who says that learning C can't be exciting?

Comment: @DavidBowling Amen to that. If I can learn half of what there is to learn in C, it will be an unmitigated success. The more I learn, the more I learn I have to learn...

Answer (score -3):

Ok, i solved it by declaring the variable n and v[100] globally.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

I also tried to use the pointer and it looks something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void read(int a[], int* n)
{
    scanf("%d",n);
    for(int i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
}
void print(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

}
void main()
{
    int a[20],n;
    read(a,&n);
    print(a,n);
}
```

And it works.

Comment: Global variable are usually not the answer. Here, they are not the answer.

Comment: Very bad solution, a cop-out. Please learn how to handle local variables.